Assembly code is crashing when passing parameters to a function
Hello I am trying to learn assembly (NASM). I watched some videos out there and now I am trying to do some codes. The code is to take a string and calculate the length of it, then pass it to a system call and have it printed. But it gives segmentation fault right after printing "Hello World!". The other strings don't get printed any more.
Here is my code:
section .data
    msg db "Hello World!",0
    msg2 db "Good Bye World",0
    msg3 db "Hello Universe",0

section .text
    global _start

_strlen:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, [ebp + 8]
    mov bl, [eax]
    mov ecx, 0

    _loop:
        cmp bl, 0
        je _loopend

        add eax, 1
        mov bl, [eax]
        add ecx, 1
        jmp _loop

    _loopend:

    mov eax, ecx
    xor ebx, ebx
    xor ecx, ecx

    pop ebp
    ret

_printstr:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, [ebp+8]
    push eax
    call _strlen
    mov edx, eax
    
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, [ebp+8]
    int 80h

    pop ebp
    ret

_start:
    push msg
    call _printstr

    push msg2
    call _printstr

    push msg3
    call _printstr

    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, 1
    int 80h


What operating system are you programming for?  How do you assemble and link your code?

In _printstr, you push eax on the stack for use by _strlen, but then fail to pop it back off again.  This causes _printstr to return to some random address instead of the proper return address.
Make sure you pop off everything you pushed on the stack when your function returns.  You can also use a stack frame setup like this:
push ebp         ; push old ebp
mov  ebp, esp    ; set up new ebp

...

leave            ; short for "mov esp, ebp; pop ebp"
ret

This setup works even if you forgot to pop some stuff off the stack and can be very convenient for human-written code.
